# Swift : Firebase Unresolved identifier FirebaseApp.configure() && FIRApp.configure()

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, swift2, firebase-authentication

i am using xcode 7.3 and swift 2.2. I have added pod **'Firebase/Auth'** to my pod file then it gives me error stating unresolved identifier for both of them but when i reinstall my pod file with out **pod 'Firebase/Auth'**. It does not shows the issue for FirebaseApp.configure().Only after adding Auth to my pod file it is showing the issue. I tried even updating my pod file but still same issue.
[image: This is my pod]

And this is how i installed pod,

[image: This is my pd file]

[image]

Can anybody suggest me how can i solve this issue.? Even restarting and cleaning also does not solves the issue..

Answer (score 10):

You just need to add 'import FirebaseCore'

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add 'import Firebase' and remove the rest import statements of Firebase.  And add
  `FirebaseApp.configure()`. FIRApp.configure() does not work anymore.